# Using the Created by ID to populate a user lookup?

Tags: process-builder, error

on creation of I case I need to be able to populate a user lookup with the current users user ID.

I have tried to achieve this with process builder and with no other criteria but it is failing.

I have used the following:

Formula

```
[Case].CreatedById
```

Formula

```
$User.Id
```

Is it possible to update this value that will then if possible be able to be changed later?

Comment: Can you provide more details what is failing? In Actions part of process builder if you set the lookup field to `$User.Id`, it should work fine. To change it later and not overwrite the value by process builder you can add a additional condition `ischanged` for lookup as false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why you cannot populate a (User) lookup related_user__c with $User.Id in a process, as that would just populate the running user.

Did I read you correctly that you want to populate a custom user lookup with the Id of the user who created a Case? If so, then process builder will work. I just tried it, and it happened for me. If I read incorrectly that you want to populate a custom lookup with CreatedById, then that won't work because when the process is invoked, the record has not been committed to the database, so it has no CreatedById value.

Comment: Also, you cannot change CreatedById once it is set. This is a system audit field.

Comment: Indeed I did test it before raising and wanted to see if there was anything catching me out. The update works on its own but as part of a series or changes, is failing.